# C# Matrix4x4 equivalent of DirectX::XMMatrixPerspectiveLH

Tags: c#, c++, directx, directxmath

I was trying to port some c++ code to C#, everything works except the perspective.

In c++ the code looks like this, which worked without distortion.

```
DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(
                DirectX::XMMatrixRotationZ(100) *
                DirectX::XMMatrixRotationX(200) *
                DirectX::XMMatrixTranslation(0,0,4) *
                DirectX::XMMatrixPerspectiveLH(DirectX::XMConvertToRadians(180),pAdapter->aspectRatio,0.5f,10)
```

and the C# code like this

```
Matrix4x4.Transpose(
            Matrix4x4.CreateRotationZ(100) *
            Matrix4x4.CreateRotationX(200) *
            Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(0, 0, 4) *
            Matrix4x4.CreatePerspective(1.39626f, 1.7777777777777777777777777777778f, 0.5f,10)
            );
```

I would assume both of these would do the exact same, but the C# code doesn't appear at all, when i remove the perspecitve it renders but everything is strecthed as expected.

I tried to remake the source of dxmath which resulted in this, it now renders as further away but its still stretched.

```
Matrix4x4 perspective = new Matrix4x4();
float ViewWidth = 1.39626f;
float ViewHeight = 1.7777777777777777777777777777778f;
float NearZ = 0.5f;
float FarZ = 10.0f;
float TwoNearZ = NearZ + NearZ;
float fRange = FarZ / (NearZ - FarZ);

perspective.M11 = TwoNearZ / ViewWidth;
perspective.M22 = TwoNearZ / ViewHeight;
perspective.M33 = fRange;
perspective.M43 = -fRange * NearZ;

data.matrix = perspective * data.matrix;
```

Im not really sure what the problem is, i read in another post that matrix4x4 is right handed so i tried the same with that one but it didn't render at all. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your perspective matrix implementation look strange to me. I suggest you try with another implementation, This one, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404890/how-to-build-perspective-projection-matrix-no-api (notice you may have to adapt some detail since DirectX and OpenGL did not use the same coordinate system)

Comment: @Sedenion i tried to implement your suggestion but it did not render, maybe i did something wrong but i tried all the combinations.
judging from this post directx doesn't use a set coordinate system anymore https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525432/d3d11-coordinate-system

and here is what i tried to implement from the dxmath source https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMath/blob/main/Inc/DirectXMathMatrix.inl

Comment: since previous comment was too big already here is the code
`float farDist = 10f;
float nearDist = 0.5f;

float frustumDepth = farDist - nearDist;
float oneOverDepth = 1 / frustumDepth;

perspective.M22 = (float)(1 / Math.Tan(0.5f * 180));
perspective.M11 = -1 * perspective.M22 / 1.7777777777777777777777777777778f;
perspective.M33 = farDist * oneOverDepth;
perspective.M43 = (-farDist * nearDist) * oneOverDepth;
perspective.M34 = 1;`

Comment: Ok, never seen this before, but why not. One detail: You can notice that `perspective.M44` must be set to `0.0f`, unlike the default value of the identity matrix. In your code you don't explicitly set this value, Is it possible that it is left at `1.0f` ?

Comment: @Sedenion can't believe i missed that, works like a charm now, thanks!, if you want to post your comment as an answer ill mark it correct.

Comment: ``System.Numerics`` is based on XNA Game Studio's C# math functions, which used Right-Handed matrices. Your source DirectXMath code was explicitly using Left-Handed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perspective matrix you use appear strange. I suggest you to use the more classical implementation from OpenGL documentation. Also, notice that you don't explicitly set the `M44` value of your perspective matrix to `0.0f` while this value is set to `1.0f` for default identity matrix. This result in a wrong perspective matrix.

```
float frustumDepth = farDist - nearDist;  
float oneOverDepth = 1 / frustumDepth;

perspective.M22 = (float)(1.0f / Math.Tan(0.5f * fovRadians));
perspective.M11 = 1.0f * perspective.M22 / aspectRatio; 
perspective.M33 = farDist * oneOverDepth; 
perspective.M34 = 1.0f; 
perspective.M43 = (farDist * nearDist) * oneOverDepth; 
perspective.M44 = 0.0f;              //< replace 1.0f to 0.0f
```

Comment: The 0 was the solution for the code in the post you suggested, my implementation of the directx code still doesn't work, and setting it to 0 there is redundant anyway since it initializes as 0, the working code based on the post you suggested is is like this:

Comment: `float frustumDepth = farDist - nearDist;
 float oneOverDepth = 1 / frustumDepth;

perspective.M22 = (float)(1 / Math.Tan(0.5f * fovRadians));
perspective.M11 = 1 * perspective.M22 / aspectRatio;
perspective.M33 = farDist * oneOverDepth;
perspective.M43 = (farDist * nearDist) * oneOverDepth;
perspective.M34 = 1;
perspective.M44 = 0;`

Comment: Ok ! so, I was correct when I found that perspective implementation strange... I edit my answers to prevent confusion

Comment: For an orthographic projection matrix (e.g. if using directional light shadows), then element `_44` is indeed 1.0f, and `_34` (row-major) is 0.0f. This is a way to easily identify the projection type.
Also note that for right-handed perspective projections, `_34` (row-major) should be -1.0f. So that makes distinguishing projection matrix handedness (or _chirality_ as chemistry grads would say) trivial as well.